# Sorting table on two related columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a mapping table like so

```
+------+----+
| From | To |
+------+----+
|   14 | 40 |
|   40 | 32 |
|   32 | 95 |
|   88 | 56 |
|   47 | 88 |
|   60 | 32 |
+------+----+
```

The table stores ids of nodes which will be mapped to each other.

So from the table above, first 14 will be mapped to 40 then some expression of 40 and 60 will be mapped to 32 and finally 32 will be mapped to 95.

I want to sort this table in order of mapping like so

```
+------+----+-------+-------+
| From | To | Order | Group |
+------+----+-------+-------+
|   14 | 40 |     1 |     1 |
|   40 | 32 |     2 |     1 |
|   60 | 32 |     2 |     1 |
|   32 | 95 |     3 |     1 |
|   47 | 88 |     1 |     2 |
|   88 | 56 |     2 |     2 |
+------+----+-------+-------+
```

In this resultset, order tells use order of mappings. If two rows have same order and group that means the two `from`'s expression will be mapped to `to`. While a `group` groups together single chain of mapping.

Is there a way of sorting the table this way using SQL query?

Comment: It seems a recursive query.

Comment: Is there only always just one chain in the table? So exactly one element to start with, then one next, one next, till the last element in the table? If there are multiple chains, how do you want them ordered?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There can be multiple chains, I'll update the question.

Comment: But no forks, correct? There can't be one record with 40->32 and at the same time another with 40->50, right?

Comment: There can be a fork. For example, if shipping address and delivery address are same then an address taken from address table will be mapped to both shipping address and delivery address.

Comment: Your new sample looks wrong. How do you get from 14->40->32 to 60->32->95? Shoudn't this be two chains: 14->40->32->95 and 60->32->95?

Comment: 32 is mapped using an expression of 40 and 60

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166023/discussion-between-thorsten-kettner-and-bhalchandrasw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extended your request to multiple chains where according to your explanations you come from the end and look for all predecessors (thus getting the 60-32 record, because you come from 32-95).

With multiple chains you also need a group key:

```
with cte (fromid, toid, groupkey, sortkey) as
(
    select 
      fromid, 
      toid,
      row_number() over (order by fromid) as groupkey,
      1 as sortkey
    from mytable
    where toid not in (select fromid from mytable)
    union all
    select
      m.fromid,
      m.toid,
      cte.groupkey,
      cte.sortkey - 1
    from mytable m
    join cte on cte.fromid = m.toid
)
select fromid, toid
from cte
order by groupkey, sortkey;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AIAYA93175

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of recursive functions.

Have a look at [Recursive queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

> ```
>  create table tbl (ffrom int, tto int);
> insert into tbl values (40, 32);
> insert into tbl values (32, 95);
> insert into tbl values (14, 40);
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl
> start with ffrom = 14
> connect by ffrom = prior tto
> ```
>
> ```
> FFROM | TTO
> ----: | --:
>    14 |  40
>    40 |  32
>    32 |  95
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f75fd8be017da468a55da92c34f2f7a)*

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl
> start with ffrom = (select min(ffrom) from tbl)
> connect by ffrom = prior tto
> ```

Comment: 1. For this to work you must look at the data yourself to find out that it's ffrom=14 you need to start with. When data changes, you'll have to adjust your query. 2. This is the question about sorting results. Your query is lacking an `ORDER BY` clause. Even if this query happens to output the rows in the desired order, this is not at all guaranteed.

Comment: @McNets Thanks for your answer, I am looking at Recursive queries link you shared.

Comment: After your edit: There is still no `ORDER BY` clause. So the result rows can come in any arbitrary order. As to `min(ffrom)`: what makes you think it's always the minimum value to start with?

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive query. First get all records where "From" does not occur in "To", then go to the following records and so on. With every step you increase the sort key.

```
with cte (fromid, toid, sortkey) as
(
  select fromid, toid, 1 as sortkey
  from mytable
  where fromid not in (select toid from mytable)
  union all
  select m.fromid, m.toid, cte.sortkey + 1
  from mytable m
  join cte on cte.toid = m.fromid
)
select fromid, toid
from cte
order by sortkey;
```